# Why is one drive running at 3.0gb/s?

Tags: raid, sata, adaptec

I have a server where I will be updating the Adaptec RAID controllers firmware and drivers soon, and so I was arcconf to check a few things.

The four disks are all the same model configured as a RAID10 volume.  In running the GETCONFIG of arcconf, I was a bit surprised that one of the drive is running at 3.0gb/s instead of 6, like the other drives.

What could be the reason for this, and is there a way to get it to run at 6gb/s?

```
Controllers found: 1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Controller information
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   Controller Status                        : Optimal
   Channel description                      : SAS/SATA
   Controller Model                         : Adaptec 6805
   Controller Serial Number                 : 
   Controller World Wide Name               : 
   Controller Alarm                         : Enabled
   Physical Slot                            : 1
   Temperature                              : 54 C/ 129 F (Normal)
   Installed memory                         : 512 MB
   Global task priority                     : High
   Performance Mode                         : Default/Dynamic
   Host bus type                            : PCIe
   Host bus speed                           : 5000 MHz
   Host bus link width                      : 8 bit(s)/link(s)
   Stayawake period                         : Disabled
   Spinup limit internal drives             : 0
   Spinup limit external drives             : 0
   Defunct disk drive count                 : 0
   Logical devices/Failed/Degraded          : 1/0/0
   NCQ status                               : Enabled
   Statistics data collection mode          : Enabled
   --------------------------------------------------------
   RAID Properties
   --------------------------------------------------------
   Copyback                                 : Disabled
   Background consistency check             : Disabled
   Background consistency check period      : 30
   Automatic Failover                       : Enabled
   --------------------------------------------------------
   Controller Version Information
   --------------------------------------------------------
   BIOS                                     : 5.2-0 (19176)
   Firmware                                 : 5.2-0 (19176)
   Driver                                   : 7.5-0 (41013)
   Boot Flash                               : 5.2-0 (19176)
   SEEPROM (Load version/ Flash version)    : 2/ 8
   --------------------------------------------------------
   Controller ZMM Information
   --------------------------------------------------------
   Status                                   : ZMM not installed

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Logical device information
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Logical device number 0
   Logical device name                      : VMSTORAGE01
   Block Size of member drives              : 512 Bytes
   RAID level                               : 10
   Unique Identifier                        : 
   Status of logical device                 : Optimal
   Additional details                       : Quick initialized
   Size                                     : 3809270 MB
   Parity space                             : 3809280 MB
   Stripe-unit size                         : 256 KB
   Read-cache setting                       : Enabled
   Read-cache status                        : On
   Write-cache setting                      : Disabled
   Write-cache status                       : Off
   Partitioned                              : Yes
   Protected by Hot-Spare                   : No
   Bootable                                 : Yes
   Failed stripes                           : No
   Power settings                           : Disabled
   --------------------------------------------------------
   Logical device segment information
   --------------------------------------------------------
   Group 0, Segment 0                       : Present (Controller:1,Connector:1,Device:0)      WD-
   Group 0, Segment 1                       : Present (Controller:1,Connector:1,Device:1)      WD-
   Group 1, Segment 0                       : Present (Controller:1,Connector:1,Device:2)      WD-
   Group 1, Segment 1                       : Present (Controller:1,Connector:1,Device:3)      WD-


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Physical Device information
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      Device #0
         Device is a Hard drive
         State                              : Online
         Block Size                         : 512 Bytes
         Supported                          : Yes
         Transfer Speed                     : SATA 6.0 Gb/s
         Reported Channel,Device(T:L)       : 0,4(4:0)
         Reported Location                  : Connector 1, Device 0
         Vendor                             : WDC
         Model                              : WD20EFRX-68EUZN0
         Firmware                           : 80.00A80
         Serial number                      : 
         World-wide name                    : 
         Reserved Size                      : 3163160 KB
         Used Size                          : 1904640 MB
         Unused Size                        : 64 KB
         Total Size                         : 1907729 MB
         Write Cache                        : Disabled (write-through)
         FRU                                : None
         S.M.A.R.T.                         : No
         S.M.A.R.T. warnings                : 0
         Power State                        : Full rpm
         Supported Power States             : Full rpm,Powered off
         SSD                                : No
         Temperature                        : Not Supported
         NCQ status                         : Enabled
      Device #1
         Device is a Hard drive
         State                              : Online
         Block Size                         : 512 Bytes
         Supported                          : Yes
         Transfer Speed                     : SATA 6.0 Gb/s
         Reported Channel,Device(T:L)       : 0,5(5:0)
         Reported Location                  : Connector 1, Device 1
         Vendor                             : WDC
         Model                              : WD20EFRX-68EUZN0
         Firmware                           : 80.00A80
         Serial number                      : 
         World-wide name                    : 
         Reserved Size                      : 3163160 KB
         Used Size                          : 1904640 MB
         Unused Size                        : 64 KB
         Total Size                         : 1907729 MB
         Write Cache                        : Disabled (write-through)
         FRU                                : None
         S.M.A.R.T.                         : No
         S.M.A.R.T. warnings                : 0
         Power State                        : Full rpm
         Supported Power States             : Full rpm,Powered off
         SSD                                : No
         Temperature                        : Not Supported
         NCQ status                         : Enabled
      Device #2
         Device is a Hard drive
         State                              : Online
         Block Size                         : 512 Bytes
         Supported                          : Yes
         Transfer Speed                     : SATA 3.0 Gb/s
         Reported Channel,Device(T:L)       : 0,6(6:0)
         Reported Location                  : Connector 1, Device 2
         Vendor                             : WDC
         Model                              : WD20EFRX-68EUZN0
         Firmware                           : 80.00A80
         Serial number                      : 
         World-wide name                    : 
         Reserved Size                      : 3163160 KB
         Used Size                          : 1904640 MB
         Unused Size                        : 64 KB
         Total Size                         : 1907729 MB
         Write Cache                        : Disabled (write-through)
         FRU                                : None
         S.M.A.R.T.                         : No
         S.M.A.R.T. warnings                : 0
         Power State                        : Full rpm
         Supported Power States             : Full rpm,Powered off
         SSD                                : No
         Temperature                        : Not Supported
         NCQ status                         : Enabled
      Device #3
         Device is a Hard drive
         State                              : Online
         Block Size                         : 512 Bytes
         Supported                          : Yes
         Transfer Speed                     : SATA 6.0 Gb/s
         Reported Channel,Device(T:L)       : 0,7(7:0)
         Reported Location                  : Connector 1, Device 3
         Vendor                             : WDC
         Model                              : WD20EFRX-68EUZN0
         Firmware                           : 80.00A80
         Serial number                      : 
         World-wide name                    : 
         Reserved Size                      : 3163160 KB
         Used Size                          : 1904640 MB
         Unused Size                        : 64 KB
         Total Size                         : 1907729 MB
         Write Cache                        : Disabled (write-through)
         FRU                                : None
         S.M.A.R.T.                         : No
         S.M.A.R.T. warnings                : 0
         Power State                        : Full rpm
         Supported Power States             : Full rpm,Powered off
         SSD                                : No
         Temperature                        : Not Supported
         NCQ status                         : Enabled
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most probably ATA (DATA) cable is damaged and maximum throughput of it is 3 GB/s. Try to change the cable or if it's a hot swap use the different slot.
Moreover, it is doesn't make any differences in 5.4k RPM drive and you will still get decent performance, so it will make virtually NO difference in your performance.

Comment: Hmm, the cable looks like this:  https://binged.it/2PeuSMa  So I'd have to disconnect all the drives.  Would a cable like this still have one faulty SATA end?

Comment: It might. You can get these SFF-8087-to-SATA breakout cables everywhere.